# Make ArrayList element case-insensitive

Tags: java, collections, case-insensitive

In my Java application i need to compare two list's element whether it is similar or not.

In short suppose i have two list declared like shown below

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    a.add("one");
    a.add("three");
    a.add("two");
Collections.sort(a);


List<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    a1.add("ONE");
    a1.add("two");
    a1.add("THREE");
Collections.sort(a);
```

If i write a condition for equality it fails as some of list's element is in different case like

```
if(a.equals(a1)){
    System.out.println("equal");
} else{
    System.out.println("not equal");
}
```

It will display result "Not equal"

So please tell me how i can make the list element case-insensitive in Java language only.

Thank and regard

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase() - http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)

Comment: The solution is not to make the *elements* case-insensitive (which technically would mean reimplementing String--one cannot extend it because it is final--with a wrapper class whose *equals* and *compareTo* methods are case-insensitive), but rather to make the *comparison* case-insensitive.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why not using instead a SortedSet with a case insensitive comparator ?
With the [String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) comparator

Your code is reduced to

```
Set<String> a = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    a.add("one");
    a.add("three");
    a.add("two");


Set<String> a1 = new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    a1.add("ONE");
    a1.add("two");
    a1.add("THREE");
```

And your equals conditions should work without any issue

**EDIT** modified according to comments. Thanks to all of you to correct me.

Comment: (you have to use a different TreeSet constructor to use the custom comparator)

Comment: You should actually *use* the `Comparator` you defined in your sample code ;-)

Comment: Also see `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` static Comparator on the String class

Comment: Note that Set lacks the indexOf method.

Answer (score 15):

You need to use

```
Collections.sort(a, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

in order to sort ignoring case, you can use the equalsIgnoreCase method on String to compare to values

You can of course create your own CaseInsensitiveList class, we have a CaseInsensitiveSet & CaseInsensitiveMap in our codebase

Comment: That's not a complete solution (neither is my post below ;-)).

Comment: As Joachim says, this will **not** make `a.equals(a1)` return true.

Comment: Yes, I posted a little too soon, I've edited my original answer

Comment: sort only would be needed if original order does NOT matter.

Answer (score 7):

You'd have to do that manually:

```
public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(List<String> l1, List<String> l2) {
  if (l1.size() != l2.size()) {
    return false;
  }
  Iterator<String> i1=l1.iterator();
  Iterator<String> i2=l2.iterator();
  while(i1.hasNext()) {
    if (!i1.next().equalsIgnoreCase(i2.next()) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also wrap your String into a helper class and implement the **equals** & **compare** methods for it.

```
public class StringWrapper implements Comparable<StringWrapper> {
    private String value;

    StringWrapper(Strig value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override boolean equals(Object o) {
        returns String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.equals(
            (StringWrapper) o).value
            this.value);
    }

    @Override int compareTo(StringWrapper sw) {
        returns String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(
            this.value
            sw.value);        
    }

    @Override String toString() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override int hashCode() {
        return this.value.toLowerCase.hashCode();
    }
}

And then :

List<StringWrapper> a = new ArrayList<StringWrapper>();
    a.add(StringWrapper("one"));
    a.add(StringWrapper("TWO"));
    a.add(StringWrapper("three"));
Collections.sort(a);
```

Comment: You should implement `Comparable<StringWrapper>`, and change the `compare(Object)` method `compareTo(StringWrapper)`. You should also implement `hashCode()`, which might get tricky.

Comment: (The StringWrapper needs to implement the `Comparable` interface - otherwise the `Collections.sort` causes a compile time error)

Comment: this is definitely the way to go (+1)

Comment: Very nice :) Love it. There are typos in the code, but beware of  the equals(...) method. This should do compare() ==0, equals is wrong and still compilable!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override the equals() method on the list so it does what you want.  Have a look at the current ArrayList.equals() and adapt it so it compares with equalsIgnoreCase instead of equals().

Comment: Or you make it take a comparator as a constructor argument.  But the problem is that both of these violate the contract for `Collection` and this could cause things to not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a Wrapper class to the List you are using, this would avoid to have inconsistent storage of the elements.

```
public class CaseInsensitiveStringList extends ArrayList<String> {

    @Override
    public void add(final int index, final String element) {
        super.add(index, element.toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(final String o) {
        return super.add(o.toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(final Collection<? extends String> c) {
        final ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(c.size());
        for (final String s : c) {
            temp.add(s.toLowerCase());
        }
        return super.addAll(temp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(final int index, final Collection<? extends String> c) {
        final ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(c.size());
        for (final String s : c) {
            temp.add(s.toLowerCase());
        }
        return super.addAll(index, temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort list of Strings ignoring case

```
Arrays.sort(myArray, Collator.getInstance());
```